# Could javascript date() be returning an invalid string for $.datepicker.dateFormat()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using the following code to set the date on a datepicker element to today:

```
document.getElementById('datas').value = $j.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date());
```

It works well except for a couple of customers for whom the date is set to 1 January 1970 (01.01.1970).

I can not get access to the customers' machines for debugging and for all the machines I have access to, using the same browser version, I get the right answer.

What could be wrong with said customers' computers/browsers that would make the code behave so strange? Could it be new Date() returning an invalid object to the formatDate function?

edit: the customers get the same results regardless of the browser they use.

Comment: Do they have their region set to USA or another one of the many regions that use mm.dd.yy ?

Comment: @TobyAllen even if they did, would it make a difference? The date object is the same regardless of region or format used, IIRC.

Comment: I can't find formatDate listd as a method on the datepicker widget in jquery ui website? http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: @TobyAllen It's not a method, it's a utility function.

Comment: I suspect there's a problem with the date setting on their machines.

Comment: Yours?  jquery's , javascripts?  What's the implementation?  Where's the documentation?  My suggestion woudl be to check regional settings before going any further

Comment: @TobyAllen It's described on the API page. Scroll down past Keyboard Interaction and it lists several utility functions: `$.datepicker.setDefaults`, `$.datepicker.formatDate`, `$.datepicker.parseDate`, etc.

Comment: Send them to a Javascript file that just does `alert(new Date)` and ask them to tell you what it pops up.

Comment: @barmar  I just came off the phone with one of the customers that had the problem and their regional settings were correct, the only difference being that they had their date displayed as dd/mm/yy in windows. I also logged the result of new Date() and that also seems to be correct. I'll mess around with my own regional and date settings to see if I can reproduce the error.

Comment: @Bogdan you should update your question with that new information.  Also post an answer back here if you solve the issue.